# Cumulants as coefficients of degree-n polynomial and conditions for real roots

Tags: polynomials, moments, cumulants

In a $(n-1)$-degree polynomial, $P_{n-1}(z) = c_{n-1} z^{n-1} + c_{n-2} z^{n-2} + \ldots + c_0$, defined by,

\begin{equation}
P_{n-1}(z) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \, \prod\limits_{j=1,j\neq i}^n (z-x_j)
\end{equation}

where $x_i$ are some real numbers, the coefficients are defined by,
\begin{align}
c_{n-1} &= n, \\
c_{n-2} &= -(n-1) \sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \\
c_{n-3} &= -\frac{n-2}2 \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_i - \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2 \right), \\
c_{n-4} &= -\frac{n-3}{3!} \left(2\sum_{i=1}^n x^3_i - 3\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_i\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^3\right)~, \ \cdots~,
\end{align}
which look suspiciously same as cumulants but aren't because the sums are *not* weighted by $1/n$. Are these some other statistical measures that are related to moments/cumulants?

Additionally, when the coefficients of the polynomial obey [see](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2325063?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents),
\begin{equation}
c_i^2 - 4 c_{i-1} c_{i+1} \ge 0~,
\end{equation}
then the of $P_{n-1}(z)=0$ are real.

In the above example since the coefficients seem to be related to the moments of $\{x_i\}$, is there a natural interpretation of these inequalities?

Thanks!

Comment: The condition $c_i^2 \geq 4c_{i+1} c_{i-1}$ is a sufficient condition (Kurtz's theorem, anticipated by Hutchinson about 60 years earlier), not a necessary one, as seems to be your implication. (For example, $(z-1)^m$ fails this drastically for all $m \geq 2$, and a perturbation yields examples with distinct roots.) A weak necessary condition is a slight sharpening of log concavity, but it's very far from being sufficient for only real roots.

Comment: @DavidHandelman thank you for your comment. I understand that the Kurtz's theorem provides only a sufficient condition but not a necessary one. I will edit my question appropriately, thanks!

Comment: Your $P_{n-1}(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \prod_{i=1}^n (z-x_i)$. Up to factors taking care of the derivative, your formulas for the coefficients reproduce the well-known [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities). Perhaps the connection with cumulants is that cumulants are also symmetric polynomials and will have some (other) expression in terms of the fundamental system of power sums.